# Does the Shadow Magic sorcerer's Eyes of the Dark feature work on all Darkness spells or just his/her own?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, sorcerer, vision-and-light

[Shadow Magic sorcerers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ShadowMagic) get the Eyes of the Dark feature (XGtE, p. 51):

> When you reach 3rd level in this class you learn the *darkness* spell [...] If you cast it with sorcery points, you can see through the darkness created by the spell.

Does this mean that if a Shadow Sorcerer casts *darkness* using sorcery points and then moves into a different area of magical *darkness* (not the one s/he created), the Sorcerer would not be able to see?

Or does the ability mean that the Sorcerer would possess the ability to see through the magical darkness created by the *darkness* spell **in general** (provided they were maintaining their own casting of the spell)?

Comment: I had never realized this, I thought these fellas could just see through them all!

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Eyes of the Dark appears to be a worse feature than the Devil’s Sight invocation which a warlock can get at lvl 2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Eyes of the Dark only works through *darkness* cast by you with sorcery points.

As you quoted Eyes of the Dark from the [Shadow Magic Sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ShadowMagic) (my emphasis):

> If **you** cast it with sorcery points, **you** can see through the darkness created by the spell.

The only magical darkness you can see through is the *[darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness)* **you** cast with sorcery points. **Eyes of the Dark** doesn't work if you cast *darkness* with a spell slot and you can't see with it through any other magical darkness created by others.